# BrowserStack - Fail Gradle command if UI tests fails

Tags: android, android-espresso, browserstack, browserstack-app-automate

I want to fail my Github pipeline when any UI tests fail on BrowserStack. Currently, Browserstack Gradle plugin provides a task `executeDebugTestsOnBrowserstack` which runs all the UI tests of the app on the cloud but does not fail the Gradle task when any UI tests fail.

Anyone know how to get notified if any tests fail on BrowserStack on Github?

Thanks!

Comment: At BrowserStack integration with Slack such that every failure is notified on a particular Slack channel.

For your reference, I am mentioning a guide on the same below:
https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/selenium/monitor-build-on-slack 

Also a daily build summary (via email) wherein you would be able to view the number of sessions that have failed/passed in the last 24 hours.

Comment: Yeah, that's helpful! But I want my pipeline to fail to incase test cases fail. Any suggestion for that?